# Swift! Create a segue only if the button is pressed! Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Alright, so for about a few days now, I'm stuck on this problem. I have a Tab Bar Controller and I have a View Controller where users of the app either create of enter their passwords, lets call it the **"Pass View"**.

The passwords are created using keychain method provided by Apple. Ideally I would want the app to first and always pop up the **"Pass View"** and then if users enter their password correctly then the app segues to the Tab Bar Controller.

Now I can associate an action segue from my enter/create button to the Tab Bar Controller, but if I do that then even if the users enter their passwords incorrectly the segue will still happen..

**Link to Image 1 Showing StoryBoard: 
[StoryBoardImage](https://www.flickr.com/photos/124829893@N03/18903848374/in/dateposted-public/)**

**Link to Image 2 Showing files: 
[files in my project](https://www.flickr.com/photos/124829893@N03/19338423370/in/dateposted-public/)**

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class LoginPassViewController: UIViewController {
    let MyKeychainWrapper = KeychainWrapper()
    let createLoginButtonTag = 0
    let loginButtonTag = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var passTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // 1.
        let hasLogin = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hasLoginKey")

        // 2.
        if hasLogin {
            loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            loginButton.tag = loginButtonTag
            loginButton.hidden = false
        } else {
            loginButton.setTitle("Create", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            loginButton.tag = createLoginButtonTag
            loginButton.hidden = false
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func enterApp(sender: AnyObject) {
        // 1.
        if passTextField.text == "" {
            var alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "You must enter a password!"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Oops!")
            alert.show()
            return
        }

        // 2.
        passTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // 3.
        if sender.tag == createLoginButtonTag {
            // 4.
            let hasLoginKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hasLoginKey")

            // 5.
            MyKeychainWrapper.mySetObject(passTextField.text, forKey:kSecValueData)
            MyKeychainWrapper.writeToKeychain()
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "hasLoginKey")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            loginButton.tag = loginButtonTag
        } else if sender.tag == loginButtonTag {
            // 6.
            if checkLogin(passTextField.text) {

 // THIS IS WHERE IF THE USER PASSWORD IS CORRECT THEN THE VIEW SHOULD SWITCH // TO THE TAB BAR CONTROLLER. 

            } else {
                // 7.
                var alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Login Problem"
                alert.message = "Wrong username or password."
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Foiled Again!")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
    }

    func checkLogin(password: String ) -> Bool {
        if password == MyKeychainWrapper.myObjectForKey("v_Data") as? String {
                return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't create segue programmatically, but you can control the execution of your segue. Give them unique identifier then override these methods:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
     //depend on the situation, you can decide to perform this segue or not
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //prepare datas before go to next viewcontroller
}
```